# intuitive meaning of sphericity

Tags: analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

i interested in  the following definition but i don't understand it because i don't understand what mean by "flat space generated by C" .
 [image]

the same definition is given by [image]

i have also the same problem with this definition, i don't know what he mean by subspace spanned by C .
i want to be intuitive with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intuitively, by "flat space generated by $C$" they mean that if you have (say) a two-dimensional triangle floating in three-dimensional space, you should measure its sphericity by looking only at disks lying in the plane of the triangle, not full three-dimensional balls. (If you did the latter, the asphericity would always be $1$ because there is no 3D ball of positive radius lying entirely inside a triangle.) Further reading: [affine hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull).

Answer (score 1):

I agree the wording is potentially confusing but it is basically saying let the largest ball you can fit entirely inside $C$ have radius $r$ and the smallest ball you can surround $C$ have radius $s$. Then define $$\quad\frac{r}{s}=1-\epsilon,$$
$$\Rightarrow \epsilon = 1 - \frac{r}{s}$$ This effectively says the inner ball is a fraction $\epsilon$ smaller than the outer ball. This matches the definition of the smallest $\epsilon$ being the **a**sphericity, since $\epsilon=0$ means the two spheres have the same radii and this can only happen if $C$ is itself a sphere. But a picture is worth a thousand words so here's a 2D example.

[image]

We can see for the larger figure it's quite a long way from a circle so the two circles have a large difference in radius (and hence a larger $\epsilon$).
For the smaller figure the two circles' radii are closer $\Rightarrow r/s$ closer to 1, which means $\epsilon=1-r/s$ is closer to zero.

P.s. Please excuse the MS Paint drawing.

Comment: but in the first definition he said "if there exist in the flat space generated by C two""" concentric """ balls .

Comment: Oops you're absolutely right. In this case either the red circle would need to get smaller or the green larger or perhaps a combination of the both would have the lowest $\epsilon$. I'm on mobile so I can't edit the figure at the mo, but I think it still helps put across the intuition.

Comment: ok,but i still cannot compute it exactly for any concentrate convex set.also,i don't know why he defined always the definition of asphericity to convex sets only!?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why it's only defined for convex sets either. Another [definition of sphericity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericity) I've seen is the ratio of surface area of $C$ to the surface area of a sphere with the same volume as $C$, which is defined for all sets with a well defined and non-zero volume and surface area.